# Per Route Formatter Configuration in Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The title more or less says it all.
I am trying to configure the JSON MediaTypeFormatter to behave differently per route.

Specifically I have two routes in my WebAPI that are mapped to the same controller.
Each route performs the same operation and returns the same data but for reasons of backwards comparability with existing consumers they must format their output slightly differently.

I could put some code in the Controller to determine if the request came in on the legacy route or the new route and change the formatters accordingly.

I could also use an ActionFilter to change the formatters where required.

I was however wondering if there is a way to configure formatters at a per route level because that is the level of abstraction where my API behaves differently. This could either be at the point of Route Configuration or in a Delegate Handler.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how much different your two JSONs are and what exactly you are doing with them, but if you ask me, I'd do it in the formatter:

```
public class MyJsonMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    private IHttpRouteData _route;

    public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
    {
        _route = request.GetRouteData();
        return base.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(type, request, mediaType);
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, System.IO.Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        if (_route.Route.RouteTemplate.Contains("legacy"))
        {
            //here set the SerializerSettings for non standard JSON
            //I just added NullValueHandling as an example
            this.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                };
        }

        return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, writeStream, content, transportContext);
    }
}
```

You would then replace the default JsonMEdiaTypeFormatter with this one.

```
    config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, new MyJsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

In Web API you can have `DelegatingHandler` that only runs on a specific route, but that doesn't really make sense since `Formatters` collection is global so there is no point in modifying that in runtime even from a route-scoped handler.

Comment: yeah, I had considered using a custom MediaTypeFormatter; your example above is v.similar to what I am trying to achieve; but I am concerned that putting the logic introduces application logic into something that should be fairly application independent. I'm being picky I know, and your solution would certainly work - but the purist in me likes to keep my concerns well and truly separated.

Comment: You could use per-Controller configuration (through *IControllerConfiguration* http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/per-controller-configuration-in-webapi.aspx) and register this "custom" formatter only for the one controller to which it applies. This way the core application still uses default formatter, but the one controller which has more requirements, uses a specific one.

Comment: I don't actually see how that really differs from using an Action Filter. Infact I am not sure I can achieve this with an IControllerConfiguration attribute because they don't have access to route/request contextual information.

Comment: Of the options available to me so far I think I'd probably prefer an ActionFilter but I still don't like it. PS: Having just put two and two together - just thought I'd say I'm a big fan of your blog :)

Comment: I think this goes horribly wrong when multiple users access the api at once. In your example you change the formatter settings while streaming on the current instance of the formatter. This formatter is shared over all threads of the API. the better way is to return a new formatter with the correct options in the GetPerRequestFormatterInstance method. This way you also don't have to override the WriteToStreamAsync method. I used a similar implementation to be able to determine using the accept header of enumerations should be serialized as a string or as its numeric value