# XMl Response from WEB API solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-serialization

I have a Web API solution which is configured to respond results always in JSON format as below

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting =
                Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
```

But now I have a requirement to respond only one of the API calls with XML Response . But if I add the XML formatter to the system

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

then all the API calls get affected.

I have a XML string hardcoded which I want to give as reponse . 
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313241/per-route-formatter-configuration-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Сonfiguration.Formatters.XmlFormatter at api level. Try below code

```
public IHttpActionResult ApiMethod()
{
  ...
  return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, Model, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

Comment: But as per your question description it seems that you have put Formatter in Global.asax. It has to be on action.

Answer (score 0):

Write the below code in your action:

```
       Class1 c1 = new Class1();//Your Model class
       var content = new ObjectContent<Class1>(c1,
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = content
        };
```